# DDD - Value object collection in aggregate results in DB impedance mismatch

Tags: entity, domain-driven-design, value-objects

Consider the case of Order/Orderline, where Orderline is an VO collection, in this case persisting Orderline to DB require a separate table with its own set of rows, being an VO this can't have a id as per DDD, how can this mismatch be addressed, given ORM used for persistence. ( validity of the example is subjective but can't come up with a better over at this wee hour, excuse me for that )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OrderLine` table most certainly does not *require* an Id since it only needs to be related to the relevant `Order`.  The `OrderId` would be included in the `OrderLine` table but would *not* be included in the `OrderLine` VO as it would be unnecessary since the association is contained within the `Order` AR.

If your database insists on a primary key, for instance, you could come up within something like `OrderId` and `ProductId` or some other combination that makes sense.  Even a synthetic key such as a `UniqueIdentifier` would be OK since this field, too, would be excluded from the domain.

Comment: Thanks Eben, also referring to Implementing Domain Driven Design by Vaughn Vernon, has come up with a solution to include a Supertype IdentifiedValueObject, hiding the details of generated unique id from the domain.